# No output on python docker cron job

Tags: python, docker, cron, python-3.8

I've been trying to set up a simple cron job in a docker container. When I build and run the job there are no errors but nothing is logged. If I go into the container I can see the crontab (i.e. crontab -l) and run the file (python test.py). Idk what I'm missing to see the scheduled job run. Idk if it's running and my log location is wrong or if it's not even running at all.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron vim
WORKDIR /app
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
COPY test.py /app/test.py
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

# run crond as main process of container
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

crontab

```
* * * * * python /app/test.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
# new line
```

test.py

```
print('test')
```

Comment: if I compare your output with https://www.linuxwiki.de/crontab it looks like your cronjob is missing the period (* * * * * instead of something like 30 5 * * 3 )

Comment: I just realized that the link above is german. You can take a look at https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux instead.

Comment: What do you mean missing the period? I think my crontab has the correct format?

Comment: look at the terminal output (here)[https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-list-display-view-all-cron-jobs-linux#ftoc-heading-2] If I understand it correctly `crontab -l` prints out the cronjob preceded  by its "encoded" period (e.g. "0 5 * * 1") but in your case one "* * * * *" is printed which doesn't seem to be a valid period

Comment: Ah I think * * * * * is run the job every minute. At least that's what I was going for when I was testing.

Comment: Just tested it with 0-59 * * * * and the same issue happened. Nothing shows up in the docker console but I get no errors and all the files are copied over.

Comment: you start crontab with RUN but this is only executed when building the image.  If you need `/usr/bin/crontab` running on runtime you need to execute it with CMD (you can chain commands using && or put all commands in a script an run this instead).

Comment: So I should use CMD /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I to reproduced your setup with a slight adjustment: I replaced your python script by a simple `echo >> /crontest.txt`. It works as expected. The file is created inside the docker container and each minute one line is appended.
This leaves you only with the question why `python /app/test.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2` behaves different than `echo >> /crontest.txt`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron vim
WORKDIR /app
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

# run crond as main process of container
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

crontab:

```
* * * * * echo "test" >> /crontest.txt 
# new line
```

1. build docker image `docker build --tag contest .`
2. run docker container `docker run -n crontest-container contest`
3. exec into the running container `docker exec -it crontest-container bash`
4. output content of /crontest.txt `cat /crontest.txt` (you can also check and see that crontab is running `top`)

Comment: Thanks for this, for some reason my debian-image was not managing to log any textual content anywhere, but when I removed the username (root) from the crontabfile, and copied it into /etc/cron.d things started working like I expected them to...